# Close button on QTabWidget not the Tabs in the QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am using Qt-5.8 over Ubuntu.
This is how my QTabWidget appears :

[image]

And the black dot is where I want the Minimize Button to happen.
One way I came across is that I can use `QToolButton *qToolButton` to create a new button and `tabWidget->setCornerWidget(qToolButton)` and then add the implementation over its click event.

But should there not be any other way to just show the minimize button as like in MainWindow or SubWindows has. Which just minimizes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimize button on top panel of your QMainWindow's instance is part of [Windows Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_decoration#Title_bar) subsystem of your OS. So you can't use similar approach inside your window as toolbox with buttons, etc.

As you wrote, try to use `tabWidget->setCornerWidget(qToolButton)` to place your custom minimize button inside your window.